# Contents inside <Script> included in the website do not load properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, script-tag

I created a web page through Html hardcoding, but none of the content inside  was loaded. The server I used sent index.html based on Nodejs and strengthened security by using the helmet package. is as follows

Oh right, the environment I'm hosting has cloudflare proxy state + rocket loader + automatic optimization turned on. I haven't encountered this problem before, so I don't know how to solve it. Stack Overflow geniuses. Please tell me how to solve this..

Error 1
link:1 Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Error 2 ( Maybe this is error code )
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-u6I07VvyW5BhxUTbnEAHBrRUw/KCbNvo='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

First of all, I added Google, MS, and Oracle's jquery CDN to solve error number 1. And to solve error number 2, I put JS in the STATIC folder and loaded it from outside, but it didn't work (loading seems to work - Console.log value exists in )